# Handle multiple redirects angular route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

Basically, we had two routes:

1. `/homepage`
2. `'/user/oldLogin'`

Previously, if no route used to match, then the user was redirected to `/homepage`, and if the user tried to access a protected route without login, then he was redirected to `/user/oldLogin` .

Now, what I want is a new route that is `/user/Login` to handle purposes of both route `/homepage` and route `/user/oldLogin`.
So for all routes, if user is not authenticated , he should be redirected to `/user/login`.

And this is my code:

```
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'hompage', pathMatch: 'full'},
  //redirect from hompage to login
  { path: '/homepage', redirectTo: '/user/oldLogin', pathMatch: 'full'},
  //redirect login to real login
  { path: 'user/oldLogin', redirectTo: '/user/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  //note that redirects will always be on top
  { path: 'hompage', component: LandingComponent },
```

But what happens is that one redirection takes place. If user is on any unmatched route then he is redirected to `\homepage` .If user is on `/homepage` , then he is redirected to `/user/oldLogin` . And if user is on `/user/oldLogin`, only then he is redirected to `\user\login`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: you can use authguard best way to do this.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the routes you have posted, the current routing is the expected behavior.
Change
`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'hompage', pathMatch: 'full'},` to 
`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/user/login', pathMatch: 'full'}`
This redirects the unmatched routes to new login.
To redirect unauthorized routes to login, use an authGuard. If the authGuard check fails, then the user is unauthorized and you can redirect to login in authGuard itself.

Comment: Is there a way,that we can do multiple redirects, that is first redirect is done from route `a` to route `b`. And then according to rule (without user interaction) if there is route redirect from `b` to `c`, then that is also done automatically?

Comment: I didnt quite get that. can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `auth guard` in angular. Guards are used to protect the routes for authorization. `canActivate()` method is used to check the authorization, when it returns `true`, the authorization is successful

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../services/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authentication: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authentication.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['login'], {
      queryParams: {
        return: state.url
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authentication.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['login'], {
      queryParams: {
        return: state.url
      }
    });
    return false;
  }



}
```

**app.module.ts**

import the guard service in your module providers

`providers: ["AuthGuardService"]`

**routing.module.ts**

`{ path: 'yourpath', component: YourComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuardService] }`